# CCNET Exec using RoboCopy fails even with <successExitCodes>

Tags: cruisecontrol.net, robocopy

So I have a CCNET project that successfully builds until I include a RoboCopy exec task to do the deployment:

```
<exec>
  <executable>C:\Windows\System32\robocopy.exe</executable>
  <buildArgs>D:\CCNETProjects\$(projectname)\Builds\Latest_Build\_PublishedWebsites\$(projectname) D:\TEST_$(projectname) *.* /E /NP /XF *.config /XD config</buildArgs>
  <buildTimeoutSeconds>60</buildTimeoutSeconds>
  <successExitCodes>0,1,2,4,8,16</successExitCodes>
</exec>
```

As you can see I have included all possible exit codes listed here; http://ss64.com/nt/robocopy-exit.html

The task executes successfully (the files get copied ok), the build results show no errors for this task, but my build still fails!

```
<buildresults>
  <message>-------------------------------------------------------------------------------</message>
  <message>   ROBOCOPY     ::     Robust File Copy for Windows                              </message>
  <message>-------------------------------------------------------------------------------</message>
  <message>  Started : Wed Jun 27 19:50:45 2012</message>
  <message>   Source : D:\CCNETProjects\FieldworkReportGenerator\Builds\Latest_Build\_PublishedWebsites\FieldworkReportGenerator\</message>
  <message>     Dest : D:\TEST_FieldworkReportGenerator\</message>
  <message>    Files : *.*</message>
  <message>     </message>
  <message>Exc Files : *.config</message>
  <message>     </message>
  <message> Exc Dirs : config</message>
  <message>     </message>
  <message>  Options : *.* /S /E /COPY:DAT /NP /R:1000000 /W:30 </message>
  <message>------------------------------------------------------------------------------</message>
  <message>                    5    D:\CCNETProjects\FieldworkReportGenerator\Builds\Latest_Build\_PublishedWebsites\FieldworkReportGenerator\</message>
  <message> *EXTRA Dir        -1    D:\TEST_FieldworkReportGenerator\App_Data\</message>
  <message> *EXTRA Dir        -1    D:\TEST_FieldworkReportGenerator\downloads\</message>
  <message> *EXTRA Dir        -1    D:\TEST_FieldworkReportGenerator\uploads\</message>
  <message>                   18    D:\CCNETProjects\FieldworkReportGenerator\Builds\Latest_Build\_PublishedWebsites\FieldworkReportGenerator\bin\</message>
  <message>     Newer              22528    ExcelHelpers.dll</message>
  <message>     Newer              48640    ExcelHelpers.pdb</message>
  <message>     Newer              33280    FieldworkReportGenerator.dll</message>
  <message>     Newer              54784    FieldworkReportGenerator.pdb</message>
  <message>                    1    D:\CCNETProjects\FieldworkReportGenerator\Builds\Latest_Build\_PublishedWebsites\FieldworkReportGenerator\Content\</message>
  <message>                    0    D:\CCNETProjects\FieldworkReportGenerator\Builds\Latest_Build\_PublishedWebsites\FieldworkReportGenerator\Content\themes\</message>
  <message>                   14    D:\CCNETProjects\FieldworkReportGenerator\Builds\Latest_Build\_PublishedWebsites\FieldworkReportGenerator\Content\themes\base\</message>
  <message>                   13    D:\CCNETProjects\FieldworkReportGenerator\Builds\Latest_Build\_PublishedWebsites\FieldworkReportGenerator\Content\themes\base\images\</message>
  <message>                   20    D:\CCNETProjects\FieldworkReportGenerator\Builds\Latest_Build\_PublishedWebsites\FieldworkReportGenerator\Scripts\</message>
  <message>                    6    D:\CCNETProjects\FieldworkReportGenerator\Builds\Latest_Build\_PublishedWebsites\FieldworkReportGenerator\uploadify\</message>
  <message>                    2    D:\CCNETProjects\FieldworkReportGenerator\Builds\Latest_Build\_PublishedWebsites\FieldworkReportGenerator\Views\</message>
  <message>                    4    D:\CCNETProjects\FieldworkReportGenerator\Builds\Latest_Build\_PublishedWebsites\FieldworkReportGenerator\Views\Account\</message>
  <message>                    3    D:\CCNETProjects\FieldworkReportGenerator\Builds\Latest_Build\_PublishedWebsites\FieldworkReportGenerator\Views\Home\</message>
  <message>                    3    D:\CCNETProjects\FieldworkReportGenerator\Builds\Latest_Build\_PublishedWebsites\FieldworkReportGenerator\Views\Shared\</message>
  <message>------------------------------------------------------------------------------</message>
  <message>               Total    Copied   Skipped  Mismatch    FAILED    Extras</message>
  <message>    Dirs :        13         0        13         0         0         3</message>
  <message>   Files :        89         4        85         0         0         0</message>
  <message>   Bytes :    9.61 m   155.5 k    9.46 m         0         0         0</message>
  <message>   Times :   0:00:00   0:00:00                       0:00:00   0:00:00</message>
  <message>   Speed :              462883 Bytes/sec.</message>
  <message>   Speed :              26.486 MegaBytes/min.</message>
  <message>   Ended : Wed Jun 27 19:50:45 2012</message>
</buildresults>
```

ccnet.log info doesn't show anything either;

```
2012-06-27 19:44:02,507 [4:DEBUG] [FieldworkReportGenerator C:\Windows\System32\robocopy.exe]    Ended : Wed Jun 27 19:44:02 2012
2012-06-27 19:44:02,538 [4:DEBUG] [FieldworkReportGenerator C:\Windows\System32\robocopy.exe] standard-output stream closed -- null received in event
2012-06-27 19:44:02,538 [11:DEBUG] [FieldworkReportGenerator C:\Windows\System32\robocopy.exe] standard-error stream closed -- null received in event
2012-06-27 19:44:02,538 [5:DEBUG] [FieldworkReportGenerator C:\Windows\System32\robocopy.exe] process exited event received
2012-06-27 19:44:02,632 [FieldworkReportGenerator:INFO] Delete merged file 'D:\CCNETProjects\FieldworkReportGenerator\Artifacts\msbuild-results-7d2f394c-2b07-4131-9cfc-4d3f05968758.xml'.
2012-06-27 19:44:02,632 [FieldworkReportGenerator:INFO] Integration complete: Failure - 27/06/2012 19:44:02
```

I'm all out of ideas.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Exit codes are a bitmask. You can get an exit code of 3 if you combine the codes for 1 (some files copied) and 2 (Extra directories detected). That seems to be the case from your output.

Comment: So you only really need 0,1,2,3 as those are the only success codes where is not error.

Comment: The doc linked in the question says "Any value greater than 7 indicates that there was at least one failure during the copy operation." You could define 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7 as success. It depends if you feel having extra files in your output folder is an error.